# VS Code Extension to search JSON

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write my first VS Code Extension using a custom search logic to find flattened JSON key-value pairs. Consider the following simplified JSON, used as a locale for example:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "name": "Animals",
        "mammals": {
            "dogs": {
                "corgi": "Corgi",
                "akita": "Akita"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that I want to be able to search for the keys as a flattened manner, such as this:
`animals.mammals.dogs.akita`.
Then the sidebar/search editor would lead me to the corresponding value in the appropriate file, following the above example that would be `Akita`.

Edit: I only need guidelines on how to start to implement the custom search function, whether it's something that could be done, I can handle the JSON parsing. As `workbench.action.findInFiles` only uses regex at most, I would need better options.

Comment: Pls show what have you done so far, or correct your question.  replace "I want to write my first VS Code Extension" with "I want somebody to write my first VS Code Extension"

Comment: @Serge I'm currently only researching ways whether a custom search function could be applied.. I've edited my question, thanks.

Comment: then start with the WebviewView example, choose a web framework you like, and fill in your needed functionality, you need WebviewView because you have UI components in your View bar (search box), you have to do all the finding yourself, VSC find will not help you with this

Comment: I wonder if returning the flattened keys as "WorkspaceSymbols" provided by a [`WorkspaceSymbolProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceSymbolProvider%3CT%3E) could work here. Searching would happen through the "Go to symbol in workspace" command. Maybe it's worth considering this option.It doesn't use the well-known search UI but is simple to implement.

Comment: Any lead on this?

Comment: @HaizadAnnuar Some time later I've found an extension called [i18n ally](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lokalise.i18n-ally) that suits my needs more than enough. Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Wonderful extension! Thanks for sharing @Illumi